# How do I run a single codebase on multiple domains?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm writing an open source application that will be deployed by developers on their own domains. There are many places where I have to reference the domain, e.g. devise's default mailer option

Where is the conventional place to specify the domain name of the application, and how do I reference it in other parts of my application?

Comment: Put it in an environment variable

Comment: @neo I did that, but i'm almost certain there's a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Rails applications there may be several areas where you need to access the domain associated with the application. Depending on the specific area of the code where you need it, you have 3 different cases:

1. code that runs in the context of a request
2. code that runs outside the context of a request, but it is triggered by a request (or may be triggered by a request)
3. code that runs outside the context of a request

To give you an example:

- a controller is run into the context of a request
- a model method is executed outside the context of a request, but you can potentially pass the context when you invoke the method. However, this is now always applicable (e.g. if the same method is executed via the CLI or a background job)
- background jobs or tasks run by a scheduler are completely outside the context of a request

Libraries that operates in the context of a request (directly or indirectly) are easy to handle. The approach is generally to detect the specific hostname from the request itself.

While in most cases this is practical, in others this is a little bit more complicated. A notable case is ActiveMailer, that is always sitting between the two contexts. In most case emails are triggered in response of an HTTP request, but not always. Moreover, there is no practical way to pass the request context from the controller to the mailer, unless you explicitly pass the `request.env` as argument to each email you want to send. But this is not the most practical solution.

For simple needs, and specifically for `ActionMailer`, I created a simple plugin called [`actionmailer_with_request`](https://github.com/weppos/actionmailer_with_request) that stores the context of the request in the current thread, and make it available to `ActionMailer`. I'm mentioning it here mostly for the sake of completeness, but I'm the first one admitting it is not a complete nor a definitive solution. It is also against the MVC architecture.

The reason is not the definitive solution, is because it doesn't completely solve the issue of making the domain available in your emails. In fact, if the mailer is triggered by a background job or a cron job, you will still have no request context, hence the hostname won't be present. Likewise, the issue still applies to all the systems outside ActionMailer that needs to access the current hostname. It could be another mail process, or whatever background/external process.

At this point, it's quite evident that just relying on the context of a request is not enough. In fact, you likely have to store the information somewhere.

You can have several different possibilities. There is no single, recommended solution. Some alternatives are:

- The Rails configuration object, e.g. `Rails.application.config.hostname = xxxx`
- A configuration system
- A constant inside your Rails application or environment

In our case, we have a namespace inside `lib` where we store all our application related stuff. We also make heavy use of the environment variables.

Hence, assuming your application is called `Something` (hence in `config/application` you have `module Something`), we have in `lib/something.rb`:

```
module Something
  def default_hostname
    ENV['SITE_HOST']
  end

  def default_protocol
    ENV['SITE_PROTOCOL']
  end
end
```

These are convenient wrappers to not expose the environment variable directly. Moreover, it allows us to exchange between a config variable, or an env, or whatever we need, without modifying anywhere else the code.

Then, in `config/environments/production.rb` you need to update your mailer setting:

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: Something.default_hostname, protocol: Something.default_protocol }
```

You can also decide to configure it in `config/application.rb` if you want the setting to apply to all the contexts.

Wherever you need to access the hostname outside the context of the request, you can use

```
Something.default_hostname
```

The convenience of passing through a method, is that you can also set a default.

```
module Something
  def default_hostname
    ENV['SITE_HOST'] || "example.com"
  end
end
```

and perhaps a warning

```
module Something
  def default_hostname
    ENV['SITE_HOST'] || begin
      warn("Please set SITE_HOST to configure your site URL")
      "example.com"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

you can set it in a Redis instance if you'd like:

https://github.com/redis/redis-rb

After the initial setup

```
redis.set("mysite_url", "www.foo.com")
# => "OK"
```

Then call it wherever you need:

```
redis.get("mysite_url")
# => "www.foo.com"
```

you can set it from a form if you need, pretty useful if you need to make it changeable from admin:

```
redis.set("mysite_url", params[:settings][:site_url])
# => "OK"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's still not probably the best way. A better way would be to set it as the default_urls :host